# Fire another command within the command handler in an axonframework application

Tags: axon

Is this a good way to fire another command within the command handler in `axonframework application`?

For example, I want to provide a ROLLBACK function, which the underlying process is read the history state of aggregate with the given sequence number, and then update the aggregate according to the history state, imagine it as following:

```
@CommandHandler
private void on(RollbackCommand command, MetaData metaData) {
    ContractAggregate ca = queryGateWay.query(new QueryContractWithGivenSequenceNumber(...));
    commandGateWay.sendCommandAndWait(new UpdateContractCommand(ca));
}
```

Will it work fine?

Answer (score 1):

**On "Dispatching commands from command handlers"**

Command handlers can roughly exist in two areas in an Axon application:

1. Within the *Aggregate*
2. On a *Command Handling Component*

In both options, it would be possible to dispatch a command from within the command handler, but I would only advice such an operation from option 2.

The reasoning behind this is that when Axon handles a command from within an Aggregate, that exact Aggregate instance will be locked. 
This is done to ensure no concurrent operations are performed on a given aggregate instance.

Knowing this, we can deduce that the subsequent command could also land up in an aggregate instance, which will be locked **as well**. Added, if the command being dispatched from within an aggregate command handler is targeted to the same aggregate instance, you'll effectively be blocking the system. Axon will throw a `LockAcquisitionFailedException` eventually, but nonetheless you'd have created something undesirable.

Thus, I'd only dispatch commands from within `@CommandHandler` annotated methods which reside on a *Command Handling Component*.

**On "your use case"**

I have some questions on your use case, as the blanks make me slightly concerned whether this is the best approach. Thus, let me ask you some follow up questions.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to introduce a command handler which queries the aggregate to be able to rollback it's state with a single command?

Would you have a command which adjusts the *entire* state of the aggregate?
Or specific portions of the aggregate instance?

And, I assume the query is targeted towards a dedicated Query Model representing the aggregate, thus not Axon's idea of the `@Aggregate` annotated class, right?